# Closing severe gap along baseboard and floors

Tags: carpentry, trim-carpentry

We have very unleveled floors along this wall that wood paneling is going up on. The wall is about 10ft long and there is almost a half inch difference in the height of the floor. The baseboard was cutdown to maintain a level top for the panel to start to go up on. Is there a way to put the shoe on to hide the big difference in height of the baseboards? You can see in the photo that it is obvious that the shoe is higher on the baseboard on the right compared to the left. We will eventually have the same issue when we run trim along the top panel that ends into our ceiling too. Thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Cutting the baseboards such that the top remains level and the bottom fluctuates with the floor, like you've done, is the right approach. For what it's worth, I had to look at the first photo several times and re-read your description before noticing the height difference -- I think, when it's all done, not one of your guests will notice. Especially when their attention will be on that nice-looking wall!

Comment: Thanks Robert. It probably is the classic case of don't tell them and they won't see it. I didn't know if I was missing something with this approach or not since we will have issue with the trim along the ceiling too.